# XAudio2, starting/stopping loops?

Tags: audio, 3d, loops, xaudio2

How can I start/stop audio looping in IXAudio2SourceVoice?

Basically it has a start/stop which starts and pauses the audio execution as well as an ExitLoop() function which stpos the audio once it has finished playing. What I'd like to do is call 'ExitLoop()' then at a later time restart the looping process. How can I do this?

Comment: Hey I am looking for this exactly, and have a hard time writing the wrapper. Since my c++ skills aren't that great. I want to use xaudio2 to play and smaple music in a windows phone 8 app. Is there any change I can get my hands on some of your xaudio2 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way that can be done is by submitting buffers to the source voice... was hopig there was a more simplistic way but apparently not so guess I'll just write a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just call "IXAudio2SourceVoice->Stop(0);"

Pass a 0 as a parameter.